# How to return a pointer (to a object of template type within a method with a template argument type)

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

This question is NOT specifically related to templates.

```
template <typename T>
T* MyQueue<T>::pop()
{
    T* object = nullptr;
    //if (head != nullptr)
    //{
    //  object = head->data;
    //  head = head->next;
    //}
    return *object;
}
```

This gives out the following error (when used T as string)

```
error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'std::string *'
```

How do i return a pointer of type `T`?

I couldn't make it work even without initializing `object` with the `nullptr`

Comment: Why can't you just `return object;`?

Comment: then it will return its address. i want a pointer to the object

Comment: What do you think a pointer is, if not the address?

Comment: A pointer actually _is_ the address of an object. So that is what you want.

Comment: Do you think it is any different without a template? Did you try?

Comment: im new to c++ from java. i know a pointer variable holds the address of the object it points to.
I was wondering if there is a way to return just the value (but without copying it)

Comment: im deleting this question as  I realize now its not relevant to templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 2 you have:

```
T* MyQueue<T>::pop()
```

Whick means that your `pop()` method returns a pointer to T.

On line 10 you have:

```
    return *object;
```

Which means you return `*(T*)object` - object, not a pointer to it.

Decide what you want to do and eighter change return type of method or do not dereference pointer before return statement.

Answer (score 2):

You are dereferencing the pointer to the object before you return it. You should just return the pointer, like this

```
return object;
```

The error you are getting is because you returning the value that the pointer points to.